# Parallel SOCKS5 proxies

Tags: python, sockets, tor

Hi I need to do multiple parallel request each from different IP, so I have two instances of `tor` initiated using `stem` module. Lets say one is running at `127.0.0.1:9150` and second on `127.0.0.1:9050`.

Then if I want to use the proxy I do

```
    socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, '127.0.0.1', 9050)
    socket.socket = socks.socksocket
```

and check my IP by

```
    resp = requests.get('https://api.ipify.org?format=json', timeout=5)
    j = json.loads(resp.content)
    print('New IP: '+ j['ip'])
```

This works for a single proxy, but can I somehow specify which of the two proxies should the `requests.get()` method use? Probably somehow limit the scope of the first part of the code?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Rather than monkey-patching the `sockets` module, here's an alternative solution.

The `requests` module already has support for using http proxies, as described [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies); for example:

```
import requests

proxies = {
  'http': 'http://10.10.1.10:3128',
  'https': 'http://10.10.1.10:1080',
}

requests.get('http://example.org', proxies=proxies)
```

Of course, you want to use a *SOCKS* proxy, for which there is no
native support.  However, the
[polipo](https://www.irif.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jch/software/polipo/)
http proxy knows how to speak to an upstream SOCKS proxy, and can thus
be used to translate between what the `requests` modules supports and
your upstream tor proxies.

In addition to your two tor proxies, you would run two polipo proxies,
and then point requests at one or the other using the `proxies` option
to the various `requests` methods.

Your polipo configurations would look something like this:

```
socksParentProxy = localhost:9050
socksProxyType = socks5
```

This would work without requiring patches to either the `sockets`
module or the `requests` module.